# How can I replace outliers with median or important value without affecting statistical information?

Tags: python, data-science, data-analysis, data-cleaning

I want to replace outliers to median value or any important value without changes the statistical information
like max, Q1, Q2, Q3, min

|  | freq | V | Cp |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 0.1 | -0.08 | 2.966100e-05 |
| 1 | 0.1 | -0.12 | 3.839830e-05 |
| 2 | 0.1 | -0.16 | 5.274840e-05 |
| 3 | 0.1 | -0.20 | 8.155240e-05 |

here is  statistical information

```
df.describe()
```

|  | freq | V | header 2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| count | 204.000000 | 204.000000 | 204.000000 |
| mean | 1747.120267 | -0.740000 | 9.809639e-04 |
| std | 3326.724353 | 0.393394 | 2.569196e-03 |
| min | 0.100000 | -1.400000 | 3.094180e-08 |
| 25% | 1.057600 | -1.080000 | 2.019558e-06 |
| 50% | 64.782000 | -0.740000 | 1.833025e-05 |
| 75# | 1252.000000 | -0.400000 | 4.336162e-04 |
| max | 9100.000000 | -0.080000 | 1.278108e-02 |

i use box plot to determine and detect outliers

```
df.plot(kind='box')
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/15NzL.png)

```
#import library and read file
import pandas as pd 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

 df = pd.read_csv('FreqCurves.csv',sep='      ') 

df.rename(columns={"     Cp": "Cp"},inplace = True) #note rename "     Cp" to just "Cp" 

df
```